# Convert a pdf file in black and white

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I've got Adobe Acrobat Pro and I have a colorful file, and now i want that file to be converted  in black and white.

*How can I do it with pro options?*

Comment: What is adobe pro and what are "pro options"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For Windows with Adobe Reader**

File -> Print

Change printer to Adobe PDF (I don't think this option is for Mac)

There should be a convert to B&W checkbox and click print. You will now be asked to save the PDF.

**Adobe Acrobat Pro** (Windows and Mac)

Tools -> Preflight

Under "PDF fixups" select "Convert to grayscale". Then click "Analyze and fix". Name the file and save